# How to create conda package for a tool

Tags: conda, exe, binaryfiles, conda-build

I am new to creating Conda packages. Here is my problem:

I have a tool that has just one binary executable program. There is no other dependencies. I tried generating a Conda package for the same as follows:

1. I made a `meta.yaml`, which contains:

```yaml
package:
  name: XXXXX
  version: 1.0

source:
  path: $HOME/bin/XXXXX/

build:
  script:
    - chmod -R 777 $HOME/bin/XXXXX/YYY
    - export PATH=$HOME/bin/XXXXX/:$PATH

about:
  license: open-source
```

2. I build the Conda package using

```bash
conda build XXXXX
```

Step 2 generates a file like:

```bash
/conda-bld/linux-64/XXXXX-1.0-0.tar.bz2
```

3. When I ran

```
conda install --offline  /conda-bld/linux-64/XXXXX-1.0-0.tar.bz2
```

it is showing up on `conda list` as

```bash
XXXXX    1.0    0    file:///$HOME/xxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/conda-bld
```

But when try fetching `XXXXX` using clicking tab nothing is appearing.

The aim of creating this package is that after Conda installation, `YYY` should be accessible inside the Conda environment.

Any idea how to get this working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues.

### Copy to `$PREFIX/bin`

The main issue here is trying to set a shell environment variable. This won't live outside the process building the package. Rather, the way Conda packages is work is by copy files into paths relative to the environment prefix. Hence, what you really want to do is copy the binary to `$PREFIX/bin` and then add the executable permissions. Something like,

```yaml
build:
  number: 0
  script:
    - "mkdir -p $PREFIX/bin"
    - "cp PromPredict_mulseq $PREFIX/bin/PromPredict_mulseq"
    - "chmod u+x $PREFIX/bin/PromPredict_mulseq"
```

### Don't rely on `$HOME`

The other issue is probably how the source is being specified. I'm not sure the `$HOME` variable will get resolved correctly. I believe it is more reliable to have some relative path (e.g., `../PromPredict_mulseq`), and better to have a tarball to point at. You may need to debug this a bit to ensure the binary is getting located. It can help to run `conda build` with a `--dirty` flag and then inspect the work folder under the `conda-bld` directory.

### Install by name with `--use-local` flag

Finally, rather than specifying the full path to the built file, one should prefer specifying by name and then including a `--use-local` flag, e.g.,

```bash
conda install --use-local prompredict
```

---

### Additional Discussion

It might be helpful to inspect a concrete example package that copies binaries. Consider looking at the `meta.yaml` and `build.sh` for [the STAR recipe in the Bioconda repository](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/tree/master/recipes/star). It simply copies the binary from the GitHub tarball upstream.

Generally, I don't recommend writing recipes that copy binaries, but I can't deny it's the path of least resistance. Instead, I would prefer compiling the software as part of the recipe. This let's the binary use dynamic linked libraries rather than being a static build, and this is one of the most remarkable strengths of Conda.

Comment: But it would be too redundant to add the build for conda, rpm, deb and so on. We can build once and create all the packages from those binaries.

Comment: @Alexis like I said, path of least resistance. But if you have a Makefile to build your code, using that to build the Conda package is not much more work than a recipe that copies binaries. Plus, Conda Forge auto-tracks any GitHub releases and rebuilds automatically. It’s a little more initial overhead, but with often the benefit that it builds for multiple platforms.